# Create GCP alerting policy for uptime check using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there any way to create GCP alerting policy for uptime check using terraform and filter value of `metric.label.check_id` of already deployed resource?

Provided examples in the terraform docs show only alerting policy for metrics not for uptime check for already deployed resource so I’m not sure if that is even possible with the terraform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figure out a solution which works in my case.

I have create uptime check and uptime check alert by two separate terraform modules.

Terrraform uptime check module looks like:

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "uptime-check" {
  project = var.project_id
  display_name = var.display_name
  timeout = "10s"
  period = "60s"

  http_check {
    path = var.path
    port = var.port
    use_ssl = true
    validate_ssl = true
  }

  monitored_resource {
    type = "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      host = var.hostname,
      project_id = var.project_id
    }
  }

  content_matchers {
    content = "\"status\":\"UP\""
  }
}
```

Then for the `outputs.tf` for that module I have:

```
output "uptime_check_id" {
  value = google_monitoring_uptime_check_config.uptime-check.uptime_check_id
}
```

Then in the alerts module I have follow terraform docs but modified them to code which looks like:

```
module "medallies-common-alerts" {
  source                           = "./modules/alerts"
  project_id                       = var.project_id
  uptime_check_depends_on          = [module.uptime-check]
  check_id                         = module.uptime-check.uptime_check_id
}

...

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy_uptime_check" {
  project = var.project_id
  enabled = true
  depends_on = [var.uptime_check_depends_on]

   ....


   condition_threshold {
      filter     = format("metric.type=\"monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed\" AND metric.label.\"check_id\"=\"%s\" AND resource.type=\"uptime_url\"",var.check_id)
      duration   = "300s"
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = "1"

      trigger {
          count = 1
      }

...

}
```

Hope it will help someone too.